# rollup doesn't build css files from my Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, node-modules, angular5, rollup

I am trying to build Node module from my Angular 5 application using Rollup. It seems it build everything correctly but somehow I can't find my app css files in build. That is why I see such a error on `ng serve --aot`

`ERROR in : Couldn't resolve resource ./some.component.css relative to [my_app_path]/node_modules/my_node_module/app-body/some.component.d.ts`

here is my rollup.config.und.js

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import angular from 'rollup-plugin-angular';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
var sass = require('node-sass');
import {nameLibrary,PATH_SRC,PATH_DIST} from './config-library.js';

export default {
    entry: PATH_SRC+'index.ts',
    format: 'umd',
    moduleName: nameLibrary,
    sourceMap:true,
    external: [
        '@angular/core',
        ...
    ],
    dest:PATH_DIST+"index.umd.js",
    plugins: [
        angular({
            preprocessors:{
                template:template => template,
                style: scss => {
                     let css;
                     if(scss){
                         css = sass.renderSync({data: scss}).css.toString();
                         //console.log( 'scss ', scss, 'css ', css );
                     }else{
                          css = '';
                     }
                     return css;
                },
            }
        }),
        typescript({
            typescript:require('typescript')
        }),
        resolve({
           module: true,
           main: true
        }),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
        })
    ],
    onwarn: warning => {
         const skip_codes = [
             'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED',
             'MISSING_GLOBAL_NAME'
         ];
         if (skip_codes.indexOf(warning.code) != -1) return;
             console.error(warning);
    }
};
```

and here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "es2015",
      "sourceMap":   true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "lib": ["es2016", "dom"]
    },
    "files": [
        "src/index.ts"
    ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
      "skipTemplateCodegen": true
    }
}
```

after build I find my application correct structure in `dist` folder with e.g.

```
some.component.d.ts
some.component.js
some.component.js.map
some.component.metadata.json
```

files but without

```
some.component.css
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Comment: Bump - what was the solution here?